# change values of array of a class in java

Tags: java, arrays, class, initialization

I am writting a program that performs an a star search throughout a map. I have created a class that hold all the nodes of the map.

```
public Node {
   Node up_node, right_node, down_node, left_node;
}

public class Star {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Node a=new Node();
        Node b=new Node();
        Node h=new Node();
        Node here=new Node();

        Node[] NextNode;
        NextNode = new Node[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            NextNode[i]=new Node();
        }
        int j=0;
        a.up_node=h;
        a.right_node=b;

        b.left_node=a;

        h.down_node=a;

        //if certain conditions are met
        NextNode[j].here_node=a.up_node;
        //what i was hoping to do is copy the node a.up which is h
    }
}
```

into NextNode[0] in this case. However it keeps returning a memory address of some sort : test.Node@10b28f30: test being the name of the package, please help!

Comment: returning where ? If you try to system.out.println the Node object you will sure end up with the Node@XXXX unless you override the toString method of the class node.

Comment: Apart from the other Node's references What `value` will be contained within each node? If you have that `value` then within `toString()` method return the `String` format of that `value`. This will solve your problem

Comment: "It keeps returning" is very vague. It's not clear where you're seeing that at all, but it's almost certainly the result of calling `toString()` on a `Node` - and you haven't overridden that method...

Comment: Quote:" NextNode[j].here_node=a.up_node;" here_node does not exists on the Node class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@override the toString() method to display the internal property of your class.

By default, java display the full class name@hashCode value.

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Java are object *references* not actual *objects*. `NextNode[j].here_node = a.up_node;` will make `NextNode[j].here_node` and `a.up_node` point to the same object. Is this not what you want?

If you wanted to make a completely new copy of the object, then you can implement that in the `Node` class:

```
public class Node {
  Node up_node, right_node, down_node, left_node;

  public Node clone() {
    Node ret = new Node();

    // copy the properties
    ret.up_node = this.up_node;
    ...

    return ret;
  }
}
```

Now

```
NextNode[j].here_node = a.up_node.clone();
```

will make a copy (although it's only a shallow one -- the copy will point to the same objects via its fields as opposed to copies of them).

I assume your confusion about the code returning "an address" comes because you tried to print a node, e.g.

```
System.out.println(a.up_node);
```

You'll get something like `test.Node@10b28f30`, but try

```
System.out.println(NextNode[j].here_node);
```

and you should get exactly the same string, indicating that they're pointing to the same object.

To get something nicer, you must override `Node`'s implementation of `toString()`. Here's an example that will give each `Node` a unique number:

```
public class Node {
  Node up_node, right_node, down_node, left_node; 

  // how many nodes were created
  private static int count = 0;

  // the number of this node
  private int number;

  public Node() {
    // increment the number of nodes created
    ++Node.count;
    // assign that number to this node
    this.number = Node.count;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "Node #" + this.number;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We know that every class that we write are child of `Object` class. When we print a child of an `Object` it prints its `toString()` method. By default it is a hashed value of memory location. So it prints sort weird things. if we `@overriding` `toString` method to return something more meaningful to us then we can solve this problem. If we can name our node class someway I think we can keep track of them easily

```
class Node(){
      String nameOfNode;    
      //contractor to keep track of where it goes. 
      public Node(String a){
             nameOfNode=a;

      }
      //when we will print a Node it is going to print its name
      public String toString(){
              return nameOfNode;
      }
}
```

Then it will print the name of the node. And it will stop showing that weird memory address.

and replace your `new Node()` with distinct name `new Node("a name")`